# How to eat this kind of cheese

Tags: cheese

I have seen so many of these cheeses but I don't know how to cook or eat them.

I am new to Europe, and have never seen this in my country of origin before.

Could you tell me how to cook the cheeses? Is it just a matter of cutting and eating?

[image]

By looking around, it sounds like this is called [Gouda Cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouda_cheese) (but I am not sure)

Comment: What makes you think it's Gouda? It looks like it says "portuguese cheese" and "cured cow, goat, and sheep cheese".

Comment: @Jefromi maybe you are right, I just found a "similar" picture on wikipedia. anyway, i don't care about the name, i need to know how to eat/cook it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cured wheel cheeses are great on their own--slice and eat. That being said, at least where I'm from we usually slice them, then put them on bread (on [Pa amb tomàquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pa_amb_tom%C3%A0quet), to be precise), and often pair them with sliced cold-cut/smoked meats. Generally, the "drier" the cheese, the more it needs to be paired with bread/meat, while sweeter/spongier cured cheeses are fine on their own.

Comment: Here there is no " Pa amb tomàquet", can you suggest other kind of bread to eat this kind of cheese please? and is it just cut and put on break or I have to but it in the oven ? sorry i am a newbaby in these stuff

Comment: (I will note that there are no strange ingredients in Pa amb tomàquet, they are standard semi-hard bread, medium-sized tomatoes, olive oil, and salt. Very easy to make too!) Any bread that can be sliced and isn't too hard (or too soft) will do. The cheese is usually sliced, the crust/wax removed, and then put on the bread--no other steps. You may want to let the cheese sit for a half hour before eating if it's coming from the fridge, though. Depending on the cheese you may want to try adding salt, butter, and/or oil to the bread.

Comment: Ok, I got you, I just need to have bread and tomatto and salt and oil, that is good, the only thing still for me is the bread, you said not soft, but not heard, here i can find [toast](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiT1trGtYzLAhVMtBoKHVvgCM4QjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sodahead.com%2Ffun%2Fwhats-your-favorite-type-of-bread%2Fquestion-1591909%2F&psig=AFQjCNFBhNe0Kh1wOfc69d57cdykngLdDw&ust=1456266464419691) or (see next comment please)

Comment: or [this kind](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv7MDVtYzLAhUCoRoKHXztCOoQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreamstime.com%2Froyalty-free-stock-image-two-kind-bread-image1598226&psig=AFQjCNFBhNe0Kh1wOfc69d57cdykngLdDw&ust=1456266464419691)

Comment: or [this one](http://searchwarp.com/UserImages/15313/cibatta%20bread.jpg)

Comment: or [this](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/two-kind-bread-1598226.jpg)

Comment: or [this](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/different-kind-bread-25611131.jpg)

Comment: do you know which one is better? or do you have a picture for the correct one that i should buy please? (I am so sorry for being like a baby, but all this society is new to me including food)

Comment: Any of those other than the first one should hold well. The idea is for the sliced bread to be "strong" enough to not fall apart when you rub the tomato against it, but to be a little bit "spongy" so it can soak in the tomato and oil. Here's a good video-recipe (you don't need to understand what they're saying, the video is good). Note that the toasting and the garlic are optional (toasting helps if the bread is too soft, garlic is something some people like and others don't): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Fm5G_KbBTM

Comment: The best thing about pa amb tomàquet is that it's a recipe intended to be prepared with whatever you can get--feel free to experiment with the different types of tomatoes, olive oils, breads, etc. It should never taste *bad* outright, and you will find a combination that you like the most.

Comment: the video is really good but definately without garlic :), thank you for your help and understanding

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your culinary experimentation :D

Comment: I will prepare it after tomorrow, and I will send you a picture :)

Comment: Looking forward to it!

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, don't eat the wax rind.

You may think this goes without saying, but the number of times I've seen people unfamiliar with a wax-coated cheese slice and eat with the wax still attached might surprise you.

(Source: lived in the Netherlands for 5 years, across the street from an incredible cheese shop.)

Comment: It's more obvious on red-wax cheeses, but yellow ones can be tricky.  And white wax on sheep's milk cheeses.

Comment: it's also written in the cheese label in the photo: "rind not edible"

Answer (score 2):

Where I live, we most often eat it on a slice of bread, use it on top of pasta, and a lot of other uses. (I often find the Gouda cheese abroad lacking taste, so I prefer the 'real' Dutch brands)

I like to eat them with some sambal badyak when I eat them with some Dutch table snacks.

Comment: why you said pasta, do you mean to cook them inside the pasta ?

Comment: No, I said I used them *on top* of the pasta, just like you'd use Parmesan cheese for example.

Comment: Dutch tapas? I that like Spanish bitterballen?

Comment: If you have a better word ;) @MarcLuxen

Comment: Fingerfood? Snacks?

Although tapa  is usualy used in the meaning of small portion of something , as opposed to racion, but outside Spain in seems to mean wel, bar snack